# speed up process to use more cpu for php script

Tags: php, cpu, process

I'm running a php script which does some operations on database in while loops and I noticed (running `top`) that it uses about 45% of cpu. I'd like to set to use like 70-80% or 90%. I tried to renice the php process so it is set to max PR 39 and NT 19 but it didn't change much. It still uses about 50% of cpu. Is there any way to speed up php script (process) to use more CPU?

**EDIT:**

I've rewritten my php script so like calculation and I/O are separated now. Based on these 3 given answers and on script's observations I came up to this 3 conclusions:

1. Process priorities - I don't think that in such a case like this it
   is useful to manipulate with it. New computers are multi-core so
   there will be always some cpu power left.
2. I/O - this will always slow down a script. When I've separated
   calculations from I/O (like queries sending) I noticed that,
   calculation came up to 100% of CPU usage and mysql (in my case) was
   about 5% cpu usage. So when I fixed that like the query was sent only
   once with array of IDs then my script needed twice less time to end then
   before.
3. Single threaded script - will take 100% of one core. I noticed that
   1 php process takes over one cpu core. Nothing to do about this so
   like `while loop` would use two or more cores (but this is for different stack exchange).

Comment: So propably your database is using the other 50% cpu, or is waiting for IO or other external events.

Comment: This depends heavily on the script itself and the system state: Is the system using database connections, i/o, threads or some other stuff that may cause waiting? And if the script is truely only doing calculations, which could use 100% of your cpu and which are not waiting for other stuff: What other processes are running, is there maybe another process more important?

Comment: There're other processes that may take about 22% cpu including `mysqld` 3-4%. In my script there is one query DELETE FROM breaking while loop, the rest are calculations (it is like cleaning table script), so could be I/O reason that this doesn't use more cpu, even if it's only one query breaking?

Comment: All counted on print screen 74%.

Answer (score 2):

Your script might be single threaded and is therefore not able to utilize more than 50% of your CPU, assuming you run a dualcore setup.

Comment: I actually think your answer makes most sense considering that PHP is not multi threaded. It IS possible to make somewhat concurrent PHP scripts depending on what OS you use using forking. http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php Not really worth the hassle in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

If the overall performance is acceptable, the observed low CPU usage of the php process is not a reason for concern. The CPU usage can be low for various reasons:

- The database may be stuck in heavy computations and the php script often has to wait for database to answer.
- The database may be waiting on I/O and the php script often has to wait for database to answer.
- The php script may be waiting on I/O.
- The php script may be causing a lot of swap activity.

To improve performance, you could try tuning your I/O system, moving the database into main memory, using faster spinning disks, using solid state drives (SSD), adding more main memory (for cache) and tuning database parameters (consult your database's admin manual).